# Have I done ghusul?

Tags: salat, ghusl

Assalamualikum,
I was gonna pray namaz today, but I had to do ghusl first, so I went and took a shower. But during my time taking shower I forgot about the ghusl part or I forgot to mention the words while doing ghusl. Is my ghusul still valid? Or do I have to go take another shower? I do want to add that all my body parts were covered in or touched by water.

Comment: Welcome to Islam SE. Questions are expected to be specific, on topic, and with some research done prior to asking. Please refer to [ask], and take a [tour] in our [help]. Which words are you referring to that you forgot to mention?

Answer (score 1):

You must intend ghusul before or during your shower. The words are not necessary as the Prophet said:

> *"Actions are according to intentions, and everyone will get what was intended."*

Hadith 1 - AlBukhary.